why vscode shows this two terminal?
every time after start vscode it always shows two terminal. what is the reason ?
how to get one terminal ?
the image below shows an problem in vscode terminal. i want only one terminal instead of two. how to solve this problem ?


what action are you performing that causes these to be created? close both of them and then start VS Code again, and then give us a procedure to reproduce their creation. if your question is why they get restored when reopening VS Code, then the answer is https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_87#_shell-integration-for-the-python-repl

after close both of them and start vscode again it still shows two terminals. everytime i delete both of them and then run the code then it has only one terminal but it needs to do everytime.

how are you running the code? what command do you run / what button (where) do you press?

i press play icon on the top right side corner (run python file)

and when you press it, two terminal get created? I'm trying to understand the exact sequence of steps that can be used to reproduce this issue from a clean setup. please cooperate.

yes it creates two terminal when i press play icon on the top right side corner (run python file)

What is the reason there are two terminals?
It's possible that you at some point clicked the + button, or perhaps mistakenly triggered a keyboard shortcut that duplicated the default terminal. Your vscode caches your terminal actions and may just be restoring what you've left behind.
How to get one terminal?
Per the Managing terminals docs for vscode:

Remove terminal instances by hovering a tab and selecting the Trash Can button, selecting a tab item and pressing Delete, using Terminal: Kill the Active Terminal Instance command, or via the right-click context menu.

